# how to bind tweetinvi xaml listview?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, tweetinvi

I'am new to tweetinvi, and now i'm stuck with databinding. it's doable to retrieve tweets and i can show up the last one in a TextBlock in my XAML. but now i like to have it in a list or gridview.

code to retrieve tweets

```
var homeTimelineTweets = authenticatedUser.GetHomeTimeline();
        foreach (var tweet in homeTimelineTweets)
        {

            textBlock.Text = tweet.Text;

            //textBlock.Text = tweet.CreatedBy.ScreenName;

            //textBlock.Text = tweet.CreatedBy.Name + ",     " +tweet.Text;

            //textBlock.Text = tweet.Text;
        }
```

Code for Xaml

```
<ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="TextBlock"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

i know i have to set x:bind and x:data ... but i can figure out how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747780/how-to-bind-a-collection-to-a-listview-in-wpf/15747937#15747937 This might help you to understand how to add items with multiple properties to a ListView.

Comment: Thanks, But i now now i have to set up a viewmodel. so can close this question.